# How can I find out how much memory a person uses on Linux?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, software-rec

Is there a utility for Linux (Ubuntu), which keeps track of things like how much memory on average a person uses?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at sar the system activity reporter.  This is an old tutorial, but sar has been around a long time so it's likely still relevant:  http://sebastien.godard.pagesperso-orange.fr/tutorial.html